# Promote to custom widget in a namespace

Tags: c++, user-interface, qt4

I have MyCustomWidget in a namespace MyNameSpace

```
namespace MyNameSpace{
    class MyCustomWidget : public QWidget{
    };
}
```

How do I promote a QWidget to MyCustomWidget in my UI form? It doesn't seem to accept a custom namespace.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Type the name of the class with the namespace included: `My::PushButton`. It works. Note that:

- Qt Designer will try and guess the header name: `my_pushbutton.h`. Change it if it is wrong.
- You should check the include paths in your project to determine if a global include for the promoted widget will work

Comment: Which version of Qt are you using? I think I must be using an old version since doing what you said doesn't work.

Comment: Right now, Qt 4.6 and Qt Creator 2.0, but I remember this working with older versions too.

Comment: Its not working for me .. My workspace name is GUI and promoted widget name is gv.. when I set promoted class name as GUI::gv and header file as gv.h to a widget I am getting "error: no matching function for call to 'GUI::gv::gv(QWidget*&)'" in my ui_.h file ? could some one tell me what I am missing here ?

Comment: My guesses: wrong include path or gv doesn’t have a constructor that takes a pointer to QWidget. Does the generated ui file include the correct header with the appropriate resolution mechanism (global or local)?

Answer (score 1):

My custom plugin works good using the following code. In this example, the namespace is not only used in the plugin but also in the class which inherits the plugin.

**Header for the plugin --- it could be used in QDesigner**

```
namespace plugin { 

class MyCustomPlugin: public QObject, public QDesignerCustomWidgetInterface
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_INTERFACES(QDesignerCustomWidgetInterface)

    public:
    MyCustomPlugin(QObject *parent = 0);

    bool isContainer() const;
    bool isInitialized() const;
    QIcon icon() const;
    QString domXml() const;
    QString group() const;
    QString includeFile() const;
    QString name() const;
    QString toolTip() const;
    QString whatsThis() const;
    QWidget *createWidget(QWidget *parent);
    void initialize(QDesignerFormEditorInterface *core);

    private:
    bool initialized;
};

}
```

**cpp file for that plugin**

Implement the class as usual, but the following methods must take into account the namespace:

```
QString MyCustomPlugin::domXml() const
{
   return "<widget class=\"plugin::MyCustomClass\" name=\"mycustomclass\">\n"
   ...
}

QString MyCustomPlugin::name() const
{
   return "plugin::MyCustomClass";
}

QWidget *MyCustomPlugin::createWidget(QWidget *parent)
{
   return new plugin::MyCustomClass(parent);
}

Q_EXPORT_PLUGIN2(mycustomplugin, plugin::MyCustomPlugin)
```

**MyCustomClass**

```
namespace plugin { 

class QDESIGNER_WIDGET_EXPORT MyCustomClass: public MyCustomPlugin
{
   Q_OBJECT

   public:
      MyCustomClass(QWidget * parent = 0) {}
}; 

}
```