# How to use my namespace in Qt UI class?

Tags: qt, namespaces

I have a custom widget called `gv` which is in my namespace `GUI`. And one UI class `cv` in which a widget is promoted to `gv`. But compiler was not accepting and throwing error and then I tried the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621550/promote-to-custom-widget-in-a-namespace).

But now getting `error: no matching function for call to 'GUI::gv::gv(QWidget*&)'` in my `ui_.h` file. Could some one tell me what am I missing here?

Comment: I'm in same situation. I have a plugin library and I need my library to include namespace.

Comment: I answered a similar question here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621550/promote-to-custom-widget-in-a-namespace/30908622#30908622

Answer (score 0):

Try promoting the widget to GUI::gv (specify the namespace when promoting). That worked for me (I have a form that includes many widgets that are defined in their own namespaces).